# sbt subproject cannot find it's dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project

I have a project tree consisting of three projects A, B and C

B depends on A, and C depends on both A and B.

A and B are checked out in C's lib/ and both build fine using `sbt compile`

However, when I compile C, the build of B fails, complaining that it cannot find certain types/packages:

```
import org.scalatra.sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object NwbApiBuild extends Build {
  val Organization = "org.nwb"
  val Name = "NWB API"
  val Version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  val ScalaVersion = "2.10.3"
  val ScalatraVersion = "2.3.0"

  lazy val active_slick= Project (
    "active-slick",
    base = file("lib/active-slick")
  )

  lazy val slick_auth= Project (
    "slick-auth",
    base = file("lib/slick-auth")
  )

  lazy val project = Project (
    "root",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ScalatraPlugin.scalatraWithJRebel ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),
        "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31",
        "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",
        "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.5",
        "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.1.0",
        "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10",
        "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.7",
        "c3p0" % "c3p0" % "0.9.1.2"
      )
    )
  ) aggregate(active_slick, slick_auth) dependsOn(active_slick, slick_auth)
}
```

where slick auth has build file

```
import org.scalatra.sbt._

name := "slick-auth"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

val ScalatraVersion = "2.3.0"

lazy val active_slick = Project(
  "active-slick",
  base = file("lib/active-slick")
)

lazy val root = Project(
  "root",
  file("."),
  settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings ++ Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.0" % "test",
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
      "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
      "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",
      "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.5",
      "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.1.0",
      "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10",
      "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.7",
      "c3p0" % "c3p0" % "0.9.1.2"
    )
  )
).aggregate(active_slick).dependsOn(active_slick)
```

and active_slick:

```
name := "active-slick"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.0" % "test",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.166" % "test"
)
```

Comment: executing `show slick_auth/allDependencies` does not show any of the dependencies from the slick_auth project.

Comment: Even more, show slick_auth/root/allDependencies DOES show the necessary deps. I thought a project for `file(".")` would become "default"

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want A and B to be just projects on which C depends, and not be really part of the build of C? Would it work for you if you changed `slick_auth` to `lazy val slick_auth = RootProject(file("lib/slick-auth"))` and `active_slick` to `lazy val active_slick = RootProject(file("lib/active-slick"))`?

Comment: Wow, yes! Using RootProject does work! That is possibly an undervalued piece of knowledge in the docs... If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use another project as a dependency (rather than its binary version) you can use [project references](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Dormant/Full-Configuration.html#project-references). There are two types of references, `ProjectRef` or a simpler version of the `ProjectRef`, which is `RootProject`.

You should change your build definition to reference `slick_auth` as

```
lazy val slick_auth = RootProject(file("lib/slick-auth"))
```

and `active_slick` as

```
lazy val active_slick = RootProject(file("lib/active-slick"))
```